# grouping / comparing the similar news stories together which are gathered from different sources

Tags: java, c++, cluster-analysis, rss

grouping / comparing the similar news stories together which are gathered from different sources using RSS feeds.

Are there any API / Code available for this.

Please help.

Regards,
Gourav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not likely to find anything that specific, but there are NLP libraries which have NLP capabilities which you can design your app around. See [NLP programming tools using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4457830/80714) which accepted [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr) as the recommended solution.

You'll likely have more luck if you relax the language constraints: much more NLP of that nature is written in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/870460/80714) (e.g. [Stanford JavaNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/index.html?edu/stanford/nlp/cluster/package-tree.html)), [C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/815423/80714), or even [Lisp](http://code.google.com/p/cl-random-indexing/).